# VBA - IE automation - .getelements

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I'm trying to enter text into an input field that has no ID.  When I inspect the element I get this:

```
<input title="Affected Customer(s)" class="custom-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="true" aria-owns="typeahead-78-1606" aria-autocomplete="list" required="" type="text" placeholder="Enter customer name, email, login ID or corporate ID" entity="incident" field-name="customer.loginId" potentially-required-field="" auto-focus="" typeahead="user as user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName for user in getList('person', $viewValue)" typeahead-loading="person.isLoading" typeahead-wait-ms="500" typeahead-on-select="onCustomerSelect($model)" typeahead-template-url="views/create/custom-add-user-dropdown.html" typeahead-min-length="3" prevent-click-event="" ng-model="person.ngModel">
```

how do I reference this input field?  I have tried many ways but they all fail.  I think my understanding is lacking and hopefully a bit of help will get me on the right track.  The code I have now that tries to locate this input field is:

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
'This will load a webpage in IE
Dim i As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element

'Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
IE.Visible = True

'Define URL
URL = "https://ewpg-app-1041.hydro.mb.ca/ux/smart-it/#/create/incident"

'Navigate to URL
IE.navigate URL



' Wait while IE loading...
'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until


objIE.Document.getElementsByName("customer.loginId")(0).Value = "test"

'click create new
'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'...
For Each aEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByName("Affected Customer(s)")

    '...get the href link and print it to the sheet in col C, row y
    result = aEle

'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection
Next


'Unload IE
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

The line "objIE.Document.getElementsByName("customer.loginId")(0).Value = "test"" gives me the error Run-time error 424 - object expected.

Thank you for any help you can provide, this will probably be extremely easy but I'm just not understanding something basic obviously.  The code above was taken from a various sites, seems to work fine.  I had the for look working for testing using different logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code instead :

```
getElementsByClassName("custom-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched")
```

Comment: ahhh...I see.  I'll try that when I get to work today.  Thank you.

Comment: I tried your code, its still telling me Run-time error 424 - object expected.

Comment: Got it to work!!!!!!!

    objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("custom-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched")(0).Value = "test"

Unsure why it didn't work earlier, lol.